# Every time i refresh the page, the form makes another db call

Tags: php, mysql

Kinda new to programming, but heres the problem:
As the title suggest, im correctly sending the data im writing to the database through the form.

```
<!-- VISUALIZZA TABELLA -->
    <div>
        <!-- MODALE AGGIUNGI -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addTreatment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addTreatmentTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addTreatmentLongTitle">Aggiungi nuovo Trattamento</h5>
                    </div>
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- FORM -->
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="nome" class="form-label">Tipologia: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="cognome" class="form-label">Durata: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cognome" name="cognome" required>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Invia</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Tipologia</th>
                <th scope="col">Durata</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php if ($bResult->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $bResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $row['cognome']; ?></td>
                        <!-- <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" value="<?php //$row['id'] ?>">Elimina</button></td> -->
                    </tr>

            <?php
                }
            } ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Unfortunately, every time i refresh manually the page, it sends others data that i sent hours ago
Here i have the PHP file:

```
<?php
include "../db_connection.php";

// INSERIMENTO TRATTAMENTO
if (isset($_POST['nome']) || isset($_POST['cognome'])) {

    $sNome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sCognome = $_POST['cognome'];


    if ($sNome != NULL) {
        
        $tInsert = "INSERT INTO test (nome, cognome) VALUES ('$sNome', '$sCognome')";

        if ($sConn->query($tInsert) == FALSE) {
            echo 'Oh';
        }
    }
}

// DISPLAY TRATTAMENTI
$tShow = "SELECT id, nome, cognome FROM test";
$bResult = $sConn->query($tShow);

$sConn->close();
```

Any suggestions on what i have to do?

(I'm also trying print a button for every row that deletes the same row)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: One common method to avoid this is to issue a redirect after the POST has been processed - ie: submit the form, process the data and then use `header` to redirect to the same page - this effectively loads the page fresh with no POST data

Comment: In addition to the sql injection possibilities - your logic is flawed. You require **both** POST parameters to be present for the SQL but use `isset or isset` which means the statement will proceed with either one or other or both. `isset` will take **multiple** arguments and return `false` if 1 or more are `not set`

Comment: `every time i refresh manually the page`...it's a possible issue, but realistically most users aren't going to do that very often. And their browser should warn them if it's going to submit the form again (unless they've previously told it not to issue such warnings). So you can implement the post-redirect-get pattern to reduce the risk, but how often it will actually happen in reality is questionable.